# Bootstrap Vue: allow only floating point numbers for text input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

How exactly do we only allow `floating points numbers` with bootstrap vue form inputs?

For example: 1.0, 2.20. For usability reasons I try to avoid the number type.

```
<template>
    <b-form-input value="text" @update="handler"></b-form-input>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        text: ''
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

In vanilla.js I would do a regex check inside the handler and return false if the input does not fit the desired pattern, therefore preventing the user to type in anything other than decimal numbers. What is the vue + bootstrap way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [:state](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input#contextual-states) and computed property and allow only numbers/dot at keypress event:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      text: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    handler() {
       return this.text ? this.text % 1 !== 0 && !isNaN(this.text - parseFloat(this.text)) : null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isNumber: function(evt) {
      evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
      let charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
      if ((charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) && charCode !== 46) {
        evt.preventDefault();;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <b-form-input v-model="text" :state="handler" @keypress="isNumber($event)"></b-form-input>
  <b-form-invalid-feedback id="input-live-feedback" v-if="!handler">
     we only allow floating points numbers 
  </b-form-invalid-feedback>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but how to you prevent users from typing in certain things? For exame the user shouldnt be able to type in, say anything other than decimal numbers.

Comment: @Asperger hey mate, check again pls, I corrected answer